# I want to build a massive social async game mode into my iOS game, is there an iOS API for that?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I’m building my 2nd game now and I’m wondering if there’s an iOS API to help me out with building a social async game. I’ve used GameCenter before (for leaderboards) but I don’t think GameCenter is something I can use for this.

Are there any open source components I can use instead? Something like the Facebook SDK?
Would I need to have the game run on a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could actually use GameCenter for some of the things you wish to build. For instance, there’s a built-in mechanism for matchmaking and turn based style games. You can have a look at [GKTurnBasedMatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

However, GameCenter does have its limitations. There’s a great [blog post](http://gameshelf.jmac.org/2012/03/apples-turn-based-game-api-and-what-it-needs/) by Andrew Plotkin that describes his experience with building a GameCenter based turn-based game. In short, using GameCenter is a bit convulted, one of the players in the match needs to constantly maintain the game state (since it’s all client based) and there is no possible way for both players to act simultaneously. Also, there are issues with players logging out of games (Apple doesn’t provide a mechanism for forfeiting the game or skipping someone’s turn).

You could always take the long road and implement the game using your own server. You would need to build several mechanisms like registration, matchmaking, push notification integration, storage and of course client to server communications.

Another option to consider would be to use [Nextpeer’s SDK](http://developers.nextpeer.com). They provide a complete solution for games that wish to incorporate a “play with friends” feature and it’s free. They take care of the matchmaking, push notifications and all server-side logic. The game itself just needs to implement some simple methods like starting a game, reporting score and ending a game. It’s pretty easy, they have a [simple screencast](https://vimeo.com/44447806) here that shows how to do it.

Comment: How is the game handled on the server side? Is there a way for me to insert server-side code (python)?

Comment: They don't really let you upload any server code, but rather let players that play your game compete against each other. All logic is contained within the game itself.